# JavaScript files imported by Webpack Encore doesn't work

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack, webpack-encore, stimulusjs

Just starting a new project with Symfony 4.4 and Webpack Encore:
Stimulus is here ! I’ve never used this and it look like it doesn’t works well for me. Is there something wrong in my code ?
I juste have a Symfony controller that render `base.html.twig` and this file contains this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/app.css') }}">
        <script src="{{ asset('build/app.js') }}"></script>
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        <button data-action="click->hello#greet">Greet</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the `hello_controller.js` contains this:

```js
import { Controller } from 'stimulus'
export default class extends Controller {
  greet () {
    console.log('Hello, Stimulus!', this.element)
  }
  connect () {
    this.element.textContent = 'Hello Stimulus! Edit me in assets/controllers/hello_controller.js'
  }
}
```

In the browser, when I inspect the code, the bundled javascript code is well "rendered" but nothing happen when I click the "Greet" button.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigations, the Encore links have to be inserted using special functions in Twig.

In fact, we should do:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
{% endblock %}
```

instead of

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/app.css') }}">
<script src="{{ asset('build/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: And you can check the documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html